# Receive Simulteneous Call to Twilio SIP End Points from a Single Phone Number

Tags: twilio, asterisk, sip

I have a phone number and a SIP domain on Twilio. So when I receive a call on phone number all the SIP endpoints must ring simultaneously and once the call is received by any SIP end point, the ring to other numbers must stop. I want more or less a configuration of a call center. I am able to call a single SIP endpoint but not multiple.

Secondly If multiple simultaneous rings to SIP end points are not possible through twilio, then I want to use Asterisk, so please guide me is it possible using asterisk to receive a call on one number and forward it to multiple SIP end points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asterisk:

```
 exten => 600,1,Dial(SIP/100&SIP/101,,o)
 ; call to 600 to get two calls to 100 and 101 endpoint.
```

Twilio:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
  <Dial>
    <Number>877-555-1212</Number>
    <Number>877-999-1234</Number>
    <Number>877-123-4567</Number>
  </Dial>
</Response>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, can you please elaborate the asterisk part?

Comment: It is really simple thing, it described in any book in first chapters. Can recommend you "Asterisk the future of telephony". Not think i can describe it better,sorry.